# Custom Multi-factor Active Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory

I'll start off by saying that I have no idea if what I want can actually be done. If that's the case, do not hesitate to tell me that I'm dreaming.

I want to create a custom active directory "authenticator" in C#. By that, I mean, I would like that whenever someone logs in, their password stored in the AD is checked first, and then a second step of authentication is performed. Only if both steps pass does the user get to log in.

Now, I imagine the above isn't too far fetched, providing I wanted to integrate this authenticator into a custom product, right?. Am I totally insane for also wondering if this authenticator can be used when, say, logging into Windows itself? Or perhaps a pre-existing product which authenticates against the AD?

If I'm not dreaming, would anyone also know of any good articles/APIs to get me going? The APIs don't have to be free, as I'm willing to part with some cash to get things moving faster.

Comment: Is Microsoft Active Directory the only directory service you plan on integrating with?

Comment: It's the only one that has been mentioned to me so far, so I'm going to say yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely feasible. However I'd like to note that, when issuing a server bind to Active Directory, you're checking the provided username (usually the sAMAccountName) and the password entered in one action. There are a few ways of doing this in C#, but many folks (including myself) have opted to use the `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace.

This is how I currently bind users to Active Directory, which then based on the result of this method, I either display the reason for authorization failure, or I allow them to continue on to their account within the application.

```
//Define your connection
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("123.456.789.10:389");

try
{
      //Authenticate the username and password
      using (ldapConnection)
      {
          //Pass in the network creds, and the domain.
          var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);
          //Since we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636 over SSL, set this to true.
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
          //To force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, use AuthType.Basic
          ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
          ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
      }
      catch (LdapException ldapException)
      {
          //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
      }
}
```

If you'd like to go a step further and retrieve properties about this user as well, [check out this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911391/set-callback-for-system-directoryservices-directoryentry-to-handle-self-signed-s/13073365#13073365).

Also, I **highly** recommend Softerra's LDAP Browser for testing anything LDAP related - it is a wonderful product, and it's free. You can [download it from here.](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm)

Hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.